# Pause animation when leaving window or entering a new tab, continue animation upon re-entering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am working on this nifty logo animation and am facing an odd issue. If you leave the tab with the animation in it and re-enter the tab a couple min later. The animation (Catches up) and spins a bunch of times and super fast. This only happens when exiting and re-entering the window after a lil time.

So i thought a solution might be to just pause the animation when leaving the tab and then start it again upon re-entering the tab. Do you think that would solve my issue? If so how would you apply it to my current animation?

Thanks!

## JS FIDDLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add event listeners to the window itself for the focus and the blur events.

Check this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6gdrQ/15

Comment: seems like the animation is broken on your link now

Comment: When you open the page, click anywhere INSIDE the result window to see the effect. That is because it is inside of an iframe and it is not the main window.

Comment: Oh okay thanks! I do however need it to play automatically without a user clicking.

Comment: There is no need to click in full screen browsers.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a time interval it returns a id, that can be used to stop the interval loop.

```
var id;
$(window).focus(() => { 
    //enter tab stuff here
    id = setInterval(rotate, 7500); 
});
$(window).blur(() => {
     //leave tab stuff here
     window.clearInterval(id);
});
```

Comment: Cool! Can you update the fiddle and link it in your answer? Appreciate it!

Comment: @PortalP I did it for you.